# Simple way to validate a date irrespetive of its format

Tags: python

I am defining a new function

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dateparse

def validate(timestamp):
    if (timestampe is a true timestamp of proper year, month, day): 
        print("Yes it is correct format")
    else: 
        print("No. It is not in proper format")

#Example:
day1 = dateparse('2018-01-01')
print(type(day1))
>> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
day2 = '2018-10-7'
print(type(day2))
>> <class 'str'>
# Now above function should predict above results
validate(day1)
>> Yes it is correct format
validate(day2)
>> No. It is not in proper format
```

What should be contents of my above defined function validate to achieve above?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want dateparse because it attempts to *guess* the format, it's not enforcing a specific format.

Instead you want to use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), with a stricter template. Also, instead of an `if`/`else` branch, you should use a `try`/`except` branch around the `strptime` call.

You can figure out the correct format to use as the template with `strptime` by reading the codes [here](http://strftime.org/).

Comment: Thanks for solution. Please, It would be great if you could let me how to use this code because I am new to python. I don't know how to use them.